# What does string[1:-1] means in python?

Tags: python, recursion, slice

What does this kind of indexing refer to in case of recursion.

```py
def is_palindrome(s):
if len(s) < 1:
    return True
else:
    if s[0] == s[-1]:
        return is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
    else:
        return False

a=str(input("Enter string:"))
if(is_palindrome(a)==True):
    print("String is a palindrome!")
else:
    print("String isn't a palindrome!")
```

Comment: It's fairly obvious if you try looking at the result: `"abcde"[1:-1] == "bcd"`.

Comment: Have you tried a simpler example, say `"hello"[1:-1]`?

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about [slicing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) in python

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. ...
[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... 
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the documentation, this expression is called *slicing* : [Python: Slicing](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html)

You can add three arguments in this syntax.

The first is the start of the sequence, the second is the end (not included) and the third is the step.

When you put a negativ arguments it means that you count from the end of your array.

So for :

```py
s = "Hello World"
s = s[1:-1]
```

You would have :

> s = "ello Worl"

For your case it is recursive to go step by step to the *center* of the string and each time you check if the string is still a palindrome. When you have only one character or less it returns `True` because everything before was OK to say that your string is a palindrome